# constructor input error in VC++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I create a constructor as follow

```
    Form1(array<System::String ^> ^args)    //HW5
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
        if (args->Length==0){
        CregArray = gcnew array<CRegistration^>(100);
        record_number = 0;
        }
        else {

        }
    }
```

After that I use a line of code to create the constructor. Basically, I want to use the case of length==0, but the compiler said there is an error. I don't understand what the compiler means.

```
Application::Run(gcnew Form1(""));
```

The error is "Error 1   error C2664: 'Project3::Form1::Form1(cli::array ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [1]' to 'cli::array ^'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in a string where an array of strings is expected.
Also, String::Empty is better practice than using a literal empty string.

Try this:

```
array<System::String^>^ args = gcnew array<System::String^>(1);
args[0] = String::Empty;
Application::Run(gcnew Form1(args));
```